# Overwrite or extend Wordpress Function » wp_html_excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress, function

how can i change (overwrite, extend) the wordpress function "wp_html_excerpt()" with my own function? It doesnt work with:

```
function wp_new_html_excerpt( $str, $count ) {
    code
}
add_action('wp_html_excerpt','wp_new_html_excerpt');
```

Thank you in advance

*** update ***

i try to remove these tags: [emoji]...[/emoji] from my excerpt output

```
function wp_new_html_excerpt( $str, $count ) {
    $str = wp_strip_all_tags( $str, true );
    $str = mb_substr( $str, 0, $count );
    $str = preg_replace( '/&[^;\s]{0,6}$/', '', $str );

    // Remove Placeholders
    $str = trim(preg_replace("/\[emoji\](.*?)\[\/emoji\]/i", "", $str));
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve..? may be posting more info would help..!

Answer (score 0):

Overriding that function with your own custom function will lead to errors. In your case, might be that you're getting an error because the function was already defined before. So I wouldn't suggest to do that.

As you can see in the source, the function definition is not wrapped in `if (function_exists(...))`, so you can't override it without errors, even if you would define it before it is defined here: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/formatting.php#L3465

#### Better solution:

Look for a function that is filterable, which uses `wp_html_excerpt`.

In your case, if you want to change the excerpt, you can use `add_filter('the_excerpt', 'my_custom_filter_function')`.

As you can see in the [source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L253), this filter passes excatly one argument. So your filter function would have to look like this:

```
function my_custom_filter_function ($oldExcerpt) {

  // Do something with $oldExcerpt, save to $newExcerpt
  // Example: $newExcerpt = str_shuffle($oldExcerpt);

  return $newExcerpt
}
```

Comment: thanks :) i don't want to change the original code of my theme.... thats the reason for the inconvenient way